# "rank" each character in a string by the index at which they appear in the alphabet

Tags: python, arrays, sorting, alphabetical

I don't know how to get for example from arr1 = ['johaj'] --> arr2 = ['2','4','1','0','3']
I'm not able to describe it very well what I mean so i hope you can understand it from this example. I need to get array of 'alphabetical indexes'.

I would be very grateful for solution, how can I do this in Python.
Thank you

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what you want to happen. The indices in `arr2` correspond to the letters in `arr1` in the order hjoja, which isn't in normal or reverse alphabetical order. Could you please describe precisely what you want?

Comment: If i go through the string 'johaj' for example, then the first on in alphabet is 'a', then it's 'h', then 'j' (here I need to look which 'j' is first in the array), then you have 'o'. So if you would sort this array, you would have ['a', 'h', 'j', 'j', 'o'] but i don't want to sort it. I need to remember the order - ['j', 'o', 'h', 'a', 'j'] and get the indexes - in this case it would be: ['2','4','1','0','3']

Comment: I think what you are trying to say is that you want to "rank" each character in a string by the index at which they appear in the alphabet.

Comment: Yes, thats what I need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for you:

```
arr1 = ['johaj']

arr2 = []
for item in arr1:
  origins = list(zip(item, list(range(len(item)))))
  origins.sort()
  ranks = list(range(len(item)))
  positioned = {origin:rank for origin, rank in zip(origins, ranks)}

  ranked = [None] * len(item)
  for origin in origins:
    ranked[origin[1]] = positioned[origin]
  arr2.append(ranked)

print(arr2)
```

Output:

```
[[2, 4, 1, 0, 3]]
```

Because `arr1` is an array, you have to iterate over that array to get each item. This means that `arr2` will be a two-dimensional array that will return the ranks for each item in `arr1`. For example, if:

```
arr1 = ['johaj', 'foo', 'bar']
```

It will output:

```
[[2, 4, 1, 0, 3], [0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to translate a string into list of alphabetical character indexes, you can make a dictionary with letters as keys and indexes as values. Then you loop your string through this dictionary and get values (indexes), that you can then append into a list.

Comment: I put it wrong there, I have array of chars - ['j', 'o', 'h', 'a', 'j'] and need to get array where will be indexes of that array - ['2','4','1','0','3']

Comment: sorry, I don't get the logic of index attribution. This is not alphabetic order, so what is it?

Answer (score -1):

I think the question needs to be explained better or example code provided, the information you have given is not enough to answer the question as is.

Looking at the information you have provided. I believe you are trying to order the array with the sorted indices, but have the order be the original array?

to make it simpler,

```
     my_string = "johaj"
     my_array = ["a','h','j','j','o']
   
     # return the index of the letter in my_array and add it to a secondary 
     array that matches the order of my_string
```

is this correct?

edit: This is the best I can come up with. I hope it helps

```
    my_string = input("word? > ")
    my_array = []
    result_array = []
    counter = 0
    my_dict = {}

    for char in my_string:
        my_array.append(char)

    sorted_array = sorted(my_array)

    for i in sorted_array:
        my_dict[i] = counter
    counter += 1

    for i in my_string:
        result_array.append(my_dict[i])

    print(result_array)
```

Comment: I tried to post a picture about what i mean. I don't really know how to explain better :(.

Comment: Exactly, thats what I need

Comment: Thanks for your help, looks like i have the solution.

Comment: counter += 1 must be in for loop, then it works but not fully because you will get with input: 'johaj' --> [3, 4, 1, 0, 3]. So there is a problem with more same chars. But I have found a different solution already. And you have another one i see